# Passing graph object to html div in plotly through callback

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Unable to pass the generated graph to html layout in Plotly. I am generating a line graph through call back and want to render it on app layout.

```
import plotly.express as px
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px             
# create a function to draw figure        
def drawFigure(fig1):
    return  html.Div([
        dbc.Card(
            dbc.CardBody([
                dcc.Graph(id='fig1',
                    figure=fig1
                    
                ) 
            ])
        ),  
    ])
       
app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Card(
        dbc.CardBody([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    drawFigure(fig1) 
                ], width=3),
               
            ], align='center'),                                     
])        
)])                
@app.callback(Output('fig1', 'figure'), [Input("submit_button", "n_clicks")])
@cache.memoize()
def generateGraph(n1):
    if n1>0:
        data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'nick', 'juli'],
        'marks':[99, 98, 95, 90]}            
         df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['rank1',
                    'rank2',
                    'rank3',
                    'rank4'])

    fig1=df.iplot(asFigure=True)
    return fig1
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

In above code fig1 is being returned from call back to the html layout under dbc.col.

Comment: What is `fig1` before your callback runs? It looks like an undefined variable you're passing into that function.

Comment: @Rishim Mittal: I think you are misunderstanding how callback functions work. As coralvanda says, `fig1` is undefined. it is generated by `generateGraph` (simply remove the `figure=fig1` in the `dcc.Graph`). Also, where is your Button with the ID `"submit_button"`?